# How to map a data list generated from some user input to another array or list

Tags: python-2.7, data-structures, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

This problem is a precursor as well as the design problem of a program I'm working upon.

We have 3 types of cards - Red (**R**), Green (**G**) and Blue (**B**). And they have to be placed on trays where there are multiple slots where each slot can hold exactly one card (i.e, *number of cards in a filled tray at any given time = number of slots in the tray*). The player/user is given a choice of choosing from the following options:

1. 3-slot tray, where any card type (R/G/B) can occupy any slot. for example, RRG, RGB, BRR etc.
2. 4-slot tray, where the first slot can be occupied by only one of the card types G or B and the remaining 3 can be occupied by any of the the card types. for example, BRRG, GRGB, BBRR etc.
3. 5-slot tray, where the first slot can be occupied by only one of the card types G or B and the remaining 4 can be occupied by any of the the card types. for example, GRRBG, GRRGB, GBRRG etc.

Now, with the program, I would like to:

- validate the condition(s) for 4-slot tray and 5-slot tray
- generate an array (a list in python) to store the permutation entered by the player/user. In all, the 3-slot tray has 27 (3*3*3), the 4-slot tray has 54 (2*3*3*3) and the 5-slot tray has 162 (2*3*3*3*3) possible permutations and combinations.
- map each of these unique permutation to another array of numbers (let us call it the ***number list***). For example, I want to map the permutation BGRG to [1,1,2,3] (which is based on the logic i[n]=1 for n=0,1 and i[n]=n for n>1); RGG to [1,1,2] and so on.

The requirement, put concisely, is:

1. accept the user input
2. validate the input according to the conditions
3. generate the array *number list*

I can always create a hard-coded multi-dimensional array/list, but I want to write a function which is flexible to any change in the logic (as mentioned in the last point above) and generate the lis. Is there an optimized, pythonic (I'm aware that python is smart with data structures and strings and can do things neatly with fewer lines of code) way to do this? Isn't a 3D list the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear to me how `BGRG` becomes `[1,1,23]`, and `RGG` becomes `[1,1,2]`. Please explain more clearly.

Comment: It is just a number generator function let us say. Like I've mentioned, i[n]=1 for n=0,1 and i[n]=n for n>1 where n is the length of the list (i.e, the number of slots in the tray). The values in the list *number list* are independent and have nothing to do with the permutation/combination, say BGRG or BRGG.

Comment: Repeating what your wrote previously doesn't provide any additional information. I can't help you with the problem unless I understand what the mapping function is supposed to do, and the explanation you've provided is unclear.